# Avoid multiple menu entries with Jekyll pagination

Tags: pagination, jekyll, liquid

I'm using Jekyll paginate plugin to create multiple pages for my blog. To make sure pagination works I have created a separate directory called `blog` with an `index.html` file. In the front matter of this `index.html` file I specify the layout, title and order:

```
---
layout: default
title:  Blog
order:  8
---
```

The `title` value is picked up by Jekyll and used to create a menu entry called "Blog" on the main page of my website. However, once pagination is enabled and all the posts are split into multiple pages, each page will have a title "Blog". This will result in multiple menu entries "Blog". I would like to have only one menu item call "Blog".

I have tried to reset the page title to "empty" for additional pages created by paginator by inserting this code into the `index.html`:

```
{% if paginator.page > 1 %}
  {% assign page.title = '' %}
{% endif %}
```

It seems `page.title` is not a variable, but an object. Therefore, the assignment was not effective.

Answer (score 3):

Allo, I don't think you can change the title from the paginator.page.title or from page.title even if you assign it `''`.

In my case to fix the [issue](https://github.com/Sylhare/Type-on-Strap/issues/73), I changed the way the title were rendered in the navbar by making sure they were not repeated twice.

```html
    {% assign name_page = "" %}
    {% for page in site.pages %}
    {% if name_page contains page.title %}
    <!-- do nothing if already there -->
    {% else %}
      <li class="separator"> | </li>
      <li>
          <a class="clear" href="{{ page.url | relative_url }}">
            {{ page.title }}
          </a>
      </li>
    {% endif %}
    {% assign name_page = page.title | append: name_page %}
    {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

So basically it adds the title to `name_page` and if the title is there twice it does not print the page title.

Answer (score 1):

How about turning it around, so checking `paginator.page < 2` while building your menu? Seems like a more logical solution to me.

Answer (score 1):

I discriminate on pagination url, which are */blog/*, */blog/page1/*, .... And I only print pages that doesn't contains *'page'*.

```
{%- for p in pages -%}
  {%- unless p.url contains 'page' -%}
    <li><a href="{{ site.baseurl }}{{ p.url }}">{{ p.title }}</a></li>
  {%- endunless -%}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could also use `unless` [control flow tag](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/tags/control-flow/) which is the opposite of `if` like this

```
{% assign tempPage = "" %}
{% for page in site.pages %}
   {% unless tempPage contains page.title %}
      {% comment %} list out the pages {% endcomment %}
      {{ page.title }}
   {% endunless %}
   {% assign tempPage = page.title | append: tempPage %}
{% endfor %}
```

here we append all the previously listed `page.title` to `tempPage` and the pages will get listed out only if the `tempPage` does not contain the current page's title in the loop

Answer (score 0):

Another elegant solution is to remove duplicate entries while sorting site pages by `order`. This can be achieved applying Liquid option `uniq` when the set of sorted pages is created. To do this copy the `header.html` file from the default Minima installation into your Jekyll `_includes` directory and introduce the change inside of the `<div class="trigger">` environment:

```
<div class="trigger">
  {% assign sorted_pages = site.pages | uniq:"title" | sort:"order" %}
    {% for my_page in sorted_pages %}
      {% if my_page.title %}
      <a class="page-link" href="{{ my_page.url | relative_url }}">{{ my_page.title | escape }}</a>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```